# Run calculating task when value changes

Tags: java, hibernate, t-sql, optimization, aop

I have a task to optimize display of statistics view which loads very long, in case of time consuming calculating process. Every value to be displayed needs to fetch some data from db, collect them, filter and do division.

My idea was to create table 'Stats' with these values ready before so it won't need to be calculated while loading (only fetch values which is much faster) but... **Result** of statistics **could be changed** from lots of places in project.

AOP lets me run a task in background after changes in application (for example I run calculateStats() method after running function updateValue()) and the values in 'Stats' table are being updated but it looks for me very difficult to handle all the places in code and find them to notify and recalculate stats. I came up with idea that the easiest way would be something like 'Run this function when row in tableA with columnA and columnB changes'. That would make me sure that I will **not overlook** anything and when making additional features in project would not need to remember and ask question 'do i need to recalculate stats after running this function?'

My question is: 
Is there any good practice and tool which notifies about changes in tableA and runs some asynchronous background function?

Example:

TableA:
    id columnA columnB
    1 foo bar

```
update TableA set columnA = 'foo1' where id = 1
```

Above change in project should run method:

```
void recalculateStats(int id, string colA) {
  //some operations
}
```

Comment: You could look into [TRIGGERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql)

Comment: this is what i was looking for, thank You!

Comment: No problem @mazakk94